# Is there any special code to store a Carriage Return in a SQL Server database field?

Tags: t-sql, iso, carriage-return

I need to store (hardcoded) a carriage return in a database field. I just find methods to do it with programming languages (for instance char(13) in TSQL) but I just want to write it BY MYSELF in a field, as it happens in HTML with &quot, &nsbp, etc...

Thanks

Francesco

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
SET @SomeVar="Hello 
     World".
```

All what do you need to write CR by hand it is just to press Enter inside of string.

Answer (score 1):

Raw SQL:

```
INSERT MyTable (col1, col2)
VALUES (1, '
')
```

There is no way in SSMS, Edit table mode.

Comment: thanks. I don't understand what you do however. I want to insert the CR between two words in a single field. Like that you insert two values in two different field one '1' and a space. I would like to have: "Hello" [CR] "World" or "Hello [CR] World"

Comment: You have do what Dalex suggested which is the same as my "Raw SQL " example. I assumed you meant in the SSMS data editor window